# `sequelize.sync({alter:true})` showing error when trying to add column in the existing table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using sequelize to create table schema with snowflake. To achieve the same I am using `snowflake-sdk`

Right now I am able to create new tables and add the data into an existing table, but I also want to write the code to alter the schema of any existing table.

For that, there is one option mentioned on the website `sync({alter: true})`
(https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#model-synchronization)

Here is my nodejs code -

```
// create new Table
const Test = sequelize.define(
  "TEST_BG",
  {
    firstName: DataTypes.TEXT,
    lastName: DataTypes.TEXT,
    favoriteColor: DataTypes.TEXT,
    age: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    occupation: DataTypes.TEXT,
    address: DataTypes.TEXT,
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

(async () => {
  // Code here
  console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");

  await Test.sync({ alter: true }).then(() => {
    console.log("alter complete");
  });
  
})();
```

But I am getting this error when I am trying to do the same.

```
Executing (default): SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM "TEST_BG";

DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 5 unexpected 'FULL'.
    at Query.formatError (C:\projects\snowflake\node-poc\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\snowflake\query.js:207:16)
    at Query.run (C:\projects\snowflake\node-poc\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\snowflake\query.js:57:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\projects\snowflake\node-poc\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:314:16
    at async SnowflakeQueryInterface.describeTable (C:\projects\snowflake\node-poc\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:166:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async TEST_BG.sync (C:\projects\snowflake\node-poc\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:947:26)
    at async Sequelize.sync (C:\projects\snowflake\node-poc\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:376:9)
    at async C:\projects\snowflake\node-poc\src\main.ts:47:3
```

Initially I created table without that `address` column. After that when I am trying to add `address` column using `sequelize.sync({ alter: true })` I am getting the error.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sequelize, but Snowflake doesn't have a `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` command, it is just `SHOW COLUMNS`. I think the address column is likely a misnomer, and something about adding any additional column is causing this `SHOW FULL` command to be executed. Hopefully that helps you dig into it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Sequelize. The query generator (in version 6 and latest main)

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/fd4afa6a89c111c6d6d0c94f0b98bf421b5357b6/src/dialects/snowflake/query-generator.js#L162

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/f6045f8f1cc48b8bb01d1ce9df0596083d3ebcf2/src/dialects/snowflake/query-generator-typescript.ts#L9

uses

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM
```

even though this does not seem to be a valid command in Snowflake.

Comment: Yes, there is an issue in version 6 and version 5 doesn't support snowflake dialect.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my local copy of the `query-generator.js` file so that the SQL string was `SHOW COLUMNS IN`. This fixed that first issue where `FULL` was causing things to fail.

Unfortunately, I think there is a larger issue because the second SQL statement to be executed when using `{ alter: true }` fails. I haven't dived any deeper than that I'm afraid.